# Calculating a specific point on a circle

Tags: geometry, circles

I am looking for a formula to calculate the point of intersection where the arc crosses the angled line (designated by the letter 'X' in the example below), only from the dimensions given.

I am trying to write a bit of software that requires this point to be calculated automatically. The same dimensions are given every time but not always of the same magnitude.

I am looking for the vertical and horizontal values for the point 'X' from the bottom left corner.

[image]

The radius always strikes tangent with the vertical line at the bottom left of the example above.

Cheers for any help.